# Is it possible to input a HSB color value and get its corresponding HEX color code as an output?

Tags: imagemagick, color-space

Let's say I have a colour in HSB format `120,100,100` and I would like to get its corresponding HEX code, which is `00FF00`.

Is it possible to achieve this with ImageMagick?
Perhaps Something like:

```
Magick "hsb(120, 100%,  100%)"
```

and with an output at the terminal, along the lines of:

```
00FF00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of, with a workaround:

```
magick xc:hsb(120,100%,100%) -depth 8 txt:
```

This basically creates a canvas of a single pixel with given color and sets the [depth](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#depth) to proper value - in this case 8-bit - so that the HEX in the output is in your desired format:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,0,255,srgb
0,0: (0,255,0)  #00FF00  lime
```

You can also set [color space](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colorspace) to e.g. `RGB` depending on what kind of HEX value you need exactly.

Not the most comfortable way, but I looked for an actual CLI color conversion tool out of curiosity and was surprised that there aren't too many, [colorconverter](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/colorconverter/index.php) was the best alternative I found, but it doesn't seem to support the 6-char HEX format.

Comment: Hey your magic solution will do just fine. Thank you for checking though.